# Can't seem to get this iOS tcp socket to work

Tags: ios, c, sockets, tcp

So, I wanted to learn how to write data back and forth over a tcp socket in objective-c and I can't seem to get it to connect to my server. I verified that my server is operating properly by writing the c code to connect with the server and it works. I just can't get the connection to happen in objective-c.

Here is the code-

```
- (void)searchForSite
    {

    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"URL", PORT, &readStream, &writeStream);
    if(!CFWriteStreamOpen(writeStream)) {
        NSLog(@"Error, writeStream not open");

        return;
    }

    NSInputStream *inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;
    NSOutputStream *outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    inStream = inputStream;
    outStream = outputStream;
    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];
    CFWriteStreamWrite(writeStream, "Hello\n", 6);
}
```

This c code works and gives me a connection on the server side:

```
void con(NSString *x)
{
int sockfd, numbytes;
char buf[MAXDATASIZE];
char *node = "URL";
struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
int rv;
char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
if ((rv = getaddrinfo(node, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));

}
// loop through all the results and connect to the first we can
for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
    if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                         p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
        perror("client: socket");
        continue; }
    if (connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
        close(sockfd);
        perror("client: connect");
        continue;
    }
    break; }
if (p == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "client: failed to connect\n");

}
inet_ntop(p->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr),
          s, sizeof s);
printf("client: connecting to %s\n", s);
freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure
if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("recv");
    exit(1); }
buf[numbytes] = '\0';
printf("client: received '%s'\n",buf);
close(sockfd);
```

}

URL is an ipv4 address.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do any of the stream delegate functions get called and if so with what?

Comment: Well, it was calling handleEvent with NSStreamEventOpenCompleted: and NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable: but now that i ran the c code it doesn't.

Comment: That sounds like it was connected then and telling you that you can write data down the stream. I assume your code at that point writes data? If its not working after you ran the C code, it sounds like your server might not be working properly?

Comment: My server is sitting on accept (blocking) and when it senses a connection it unblocks and logs something. When I run the c code in the client side, it gives me the log statement. When I run the objective-c code it doesn't. Even when I was getting NSStreamOpenComplete I was not getting anything on the server side.

Comment: `CFWriteStreamWrite(writeStream, "Hello\n", 6);` That code should be in your delegate after it indicates the output stream has capacity? You have it after you open the stream up, but its not connected at that point.

Comment: Still nothing. I have this:

Comment: [outStream write:rawstring maxLength:strlen(rawstring)];

Comment: I just ran both codes one after the other in the same run. Got connection from the c code. No connection objective-c code. No handle events either.

Comment: Final thought is do not use your variable outStream: Use the variable passed for the stream to the handleEvent function in case its different in some way.